# How can I test for exclusive access to the scratch gdb?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have an application that uses the scratch geodatabase. Upon completion of our work, we delete the scratch geodatabase. The next time our app runs, scratch gets recreated automatically. How do I test for exclusive access to scratch prior to attempting the delete? During some recent debug activities, I had ArcMap open and was consuming some of the feature classes in the gdb. This caused an error when the delete process ran.

Comment: I'm not sure but you may be able to check for a lock file in the GDB which may indicate a fc is open elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need the exclusive access for is to check if it is safe to delete the geodatabase, you could just put the delete command in a try block and ignore any exceptions. Something like

```
try:
  arcpy.Delete_management(your gdb here)
except:
  pass
```

If it is in use it will throw a specific exception (ERROR 000464), detailed here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000052000000